# I have installed CloudReady on a Mecer laptop, but I get DCHP lookup failed when I try to connect to a WiFi connection

Tags: wireless-networking

I did in fact get a connection a few times, I'm not sure what I did.  Then for some reason it just stopped.

On other forums I have seen the advice to reboot the computer and reboot the router. I tried installing a USB WiFi device.  I reconfigured the router to use WPA/WPA2 PSK Security (it was originally on WPA2 PSK).  All to avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but ...

I installed a mesh wifi router and it's satellites, and now my Mecer's CloudReady connects to the internet via that setup.  Maybe either Mecer or CloudReady are a bit flaky.